# how to submit jsf form with curl

Tags: php, jsf, curl, jsf-2

I am new to Java and JSF,

I was looking for some way to send a query term to [toysrus.co.uk](http://toysrus.co.uk)

I have already worked on php curl and I can handle it at my own, and I have coded my function which sends query term...

My issue is I am unable to create the query term and and I cant find a way to create a url in which I can add my query parameter so that I can curl this page.....

can somebody guide me how I can create the search url for [toysrus.co.uk](http://toysrus.co.uk)

what I want is, I will add my parameter in URL and the curl script will send this request to the site and I will get the searched product...

I want something like

http://www.toysrus.co.uk/index.jsf?seach=MYTERM

this is just an example what I want...

can somebody help me create the search URL for the said web site? being totally new to JSF, I am unable to do it...

also, when I googled on JSF and tried searching for helping material, I found not enough stuff on JSF

thanks for help..

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Are you asking someone to reverse-engineer the toysrus query string format for you?

Comment: some what yes, a URL, through which I can find a product on that site

Comment: Have you tried submitting a search on the site, and experimenting with the URL it provides?

Comment: I have tried searching the site, and so far, I am unable to find any specific pattern so for...I have tried fire-bugging the page and looking for parameters and action, but I am not clear how to create url from this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to search the site just by changing the search term in the URL query string.

I went to the main page and typed "seriously" into the search box. Here's the address it sent me to:

http://www.toysrus.co.uk/index.jsf?fh_eds=%3f&fh_view_size=10&fh_start_index=0&fh_location=%2f%2ftrus%2fen_GB%2fcategories%3C%7btrus_trus%7d%2fitemtype%3dproduct%2f%24s%3dseriously&media=web

See where the search term shows up there? You can change that to any other word and it will search for that. Want to search for multiple terms, or a phrase? Try typing them into the search box and see how they're encoded in the URL. You can probably also remove or change some of those other parameters if you experiment with it.

Comment: thanks for the help bro, look, I got SKU to be seached on site,like  110671 or 114545, I will input this in search bar, and want the result...infact, I am working on an app, which will get SKU from database and will search item on this site to see whether it exists or not

Comment: yes, I got the idea, very very thanks bro, thanks for the help, it was rather easy then I thought, i was confused over the jsf thing, thanks bro